# Accessing files/folders across OS partitions

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Is it possible to open up Ubuntu and read a .docx file from my Windows partition? Are there any non-obvious ramifications for doing so (corrupting files,unable to access partition, etc)?

And then a second side-question: if it is indeed possible to access files from another os on the same machine, what does that mean for the computer's information security if anyone with a Linux live boot thumb drive can access the anything on the hard drive(s) connected to the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to open up Ubuntu and read a .docx file from my Windows partition?

Certainly.

> Are there any non-obvious ramifications for doing so (corrupting files, unable to access partition, etc)?

Well, the MS Office file formats aren't the best supported, so you might cause some unexpected change if you wrote to the file. The NTFS driver is fairly stable, so filesystem-level corruption is unlikely.

> If it is indeed possible to access files from another os on the same machine, what does that mean for the computer's information security if anyone with a Linux live boot thumb drive can access the anything on the hard drive(s) connected to the machine?

An attacker has physical access to the system?

## Game Over.<sup>*</sup>

<sup><sup>*</sup> Full-disk encryption might help.</sup>

Comment: I wish I had enough rep to upvote you! But I was just giving the example of MS Office formats, in general is writing across OS's a bad idea? Also, why does physical access = game over? In what aspects are you able to compromise a system physically but not remotely?

Comment: @yazan Ubuntu will give you unrestricted access to Windows files, so you might accidentally modify a system file that you wouldn't ordinarily have access to. Writing across OS's isn't a bad idea as long as you stick to files you know are safe. If I have access to the system, I can just take the hard disk and do whatever I want with it.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is that there was a reddit post a few days ago about having access to a windows machine and a linux liveboot, you can manipulate the way that windows runs sticky keys to reset the password (whether intent is malicious or not). I want to try it out, but I don't want to accidentally screw something up. Thanks for your thorough explanations!